# Add a second data series to a sub-plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

So I have this code which produces subplots nicely, laid out in a grid. Data is in Pandas DataFrames.

I can't figure out how to add a second data series to the subplots?
So now I plot `fullyrs.Units` and I want to add `merged2.fcast.plot(style='r')` I seem to be missing a reference to get the figure for the subplot? A few things I've tried end up with plots outside the "loop".

```
#area_tabs=list(map(str, range(1, 28)))
area_tabs=['1','2','3']
nrows = int(math.ceil(len(area_tabs) / 2.))
figlen=nrows*7 #adjust the figure size height to be sized to the number of rows
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 25,figlen 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, 2, sharey=False)
for ax, area_tabs in zip(axs.flat, area_tabs):  
    fullyrs,lastq,fcast_yr,projections,yrahead,aname,actdf,merged2,mergederrs,montdist,ols_test, mergedfcst=do_projections(actdf,aname)
#    ax=merged2.fcast.plot(style='r') <<<< I want to get this to plot in the same sub-plot as below
    fullyrs.Units.plot(ax=ax, title='Area: {0} Forecast for 2014 {1} vs. Actual 2013 of {2} '.format(unicode(aname),unicode(merged2['fcast'][-1:].values), lastyrtot))
```

Comment: You've already created `ax` with `plt.subplots` so don't you just need to pass `ax=ax` to `merged2.fcast.plot` instead of setting `ax=...`?

Comment: @Rauparaha, so right! Thanks! If you make answer I can mark it

Comment: Done, glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already created `ax` with `plt.subplots` so you just need to pass `ax=ax` to `merged2.fcast.plot` pandas call instead of setting `ax=...`, which creates a new axis. eg.

```
for ax, area_tabs in zip(axs.flat, area_tabs):  
    fullyrs,lastq,fcast_yr,projections,yrahead,aname,actdf,merged2,mergederrs,montdist,ols_test, mergedfcst=do_projections(actdf,aname)
    merged2.fcast.plot(ax=ax, style='r') <<<< I want to get this to plot in the same sub-plot as below
    fullyrs.Units.plot(ax=ax, title='Area: {0} Forecast for 2014 {1} vs. Actual 2013 of {2} '.format(unicode(aname),unicode(merged2['fcast'][-1:].values), lastyrtot))
```

You probably already know this but you could also set the figure size with `fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, 2, sharey=False, figsize=(25, 7*nrows))` instead of setting it globally in the `rcparams`. Of course, you may have other figures you want to control in the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the last tip also! still very early learning MPL/pyplot